# Kubernetes get nodes not returning master node

Tags: kubernetes

I am running kubernetes on AWS using centos. I have 1 master node and 10 worker nodes. When i do kubectl get nodes, it does not give me master node. It returns the 10 worker nodes though.

Any idea what is the mistake i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Looks like issue with the kubeconfig on the master node. Its pointing to the wrong client certificate. It worked once i fixed it.